# CPP array memory allocation

Tags: c++, arrays

Here I am declaring array length before taking input for n. At the time of array declaration n=0.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    int sum=0;
    int arr[n]={};
    cin >> n;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        cin >> arr[i];
        cout << arr[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

for below input
6
1 2 3 4 5 6

I am getting this output 1234.

Can someone please explain the reason?

Comment: You invoked *undefined behavior*. Determining the reason for this specific result will require detailed information of your environment.

Comment: Why do you assume `n` would be zero?

Comment: @MikeCAT trying to run code on hackerrank platform. https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/simple-array-sum/problem

Comment: Even though some compilers allow `int arr[n]={};`, it's not valid in the standard C++ as the length must be known at compile-time. You should be using `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @churill cout<<n

Comment: @Kathapatel You got lucky. `n` is uninitialized and could have any other value, and reading from it causes undefined behavior.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes, I am new to CPP and trying to review someone else's code. Not able to justify why getting this output with this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here I am declaring array length before taking input for n.

Yes, but that's no valid C++. It's a compiler specific extension. See [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

> At the time of array declaration n=0.

That's wrong. `n` has not been initialized, so it contains garbage data (which *could* be 0). Reading `n` invokes undefined behaviour.

Even if `n` would be 0, the loop would access the array out of bounds and undefined behaviour is invoked again.

Discussing the output of a program that invokes undefined behaviour is pointless - anything might happen. The only reasonbale thing is to avoid UB. Some good practices to do this:

- Always initialize variables to a reasonable value
- use `std::vector` instead of plain arrays/VLAs.